How to get http path from h2c in net.conn in go
I have a net.Conn, there is a h2c request in it, I want to write a func to extract path in it(from first headers frame)
// Get path form http2
func extractPathFromH2Request(conn net.Conn) string {
    framer := http2.NewFramer(io.Discard, conn)

    for {
        frame, err := framer.ReadFrame()
        if err != nil {
            return ""
        }

        // find headers frame
        if f, ok := frame.(*http2.HeadersFrame); ok {
            decoder := hpack.NewDecoder(4096, func(hf hpack.HeaderField) {})
            headerBlock := f.HeaderBlockFragment()

            hf, err := decoder.DecodeFull(headerBlock)
            if err != nil {
                return ""
            }
            path := func(headers []hpack.HeaderField) string {
                for _, header := range headers {
                    if header.Name == ":path" {
                        return header.Value
                    }
                }
                return ""
            }

            return path(hf)
        }
    }
}

it could return the path. However, I checked the forwarded traffic, the first headers frame is disappeared(?)
I guess after the func read the conn, the data inside was moved out of the buffer, resulting in the disappearance of the headers frame
I want to input the net.Conn and return the path in first headers frame without affect other part
